# How to give password directly while doing ssh command?

Tags: ssh

I am using Putty to connect to host xxxxxx. I want to produce a shell script in which I should give the command `ssh user@yyyyyy` along with my password instead of giving it when prompted.

Comment: Here is the answer [link](http://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)

Comment: @RubanSavvy That link goes over how to configure SSH keys, which is only tangential to the question.

Comment: This has the sound of an XY problem. Have you considered using SSH keys? If you're going to pass your password as an argument to a script, that argument will be visible to anyone by using `ps`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command `putty.exe -ssh root@mysite.com -pw mypassword` from cmd.

Comment: Can you use shell script in putty?

Comment: @RubanSavvy Putty is just the client, it doesn't run shell scripts.

Comment: Before you run this command, you should add the path of putty.exe to your system environment `path`. Then you can use this command in both Windows Command Line or Powershell. BTW, why don't you just install `ssh` client in your devbox. Small suggestion, if you install `git` in windows, you can have a built-in ssh client.

Comment: Hey I know that, BTW putty doesn't suits to the question. I was mentioning that @ChrisDown

Answer (score 1):

**This is an unsafe practice. You should never store your SSH password in plain text. Use an encrypted key.**

The best-practice method is to use SSH keys.

```
$> putty.exe -ssh -i /path/to/private.pke user@host
```

PuTTYGEN.exe is the tool you use to generate the keys on Windows.

ssh-keygen is the tool you use to generate the keys on Linux.

[Key-Based SSH Authentication](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/use-public-key-authentication-with-ssh)